# How do I stop duplicate pending orders from being created

Tags: commerce

Using drupal 7.63, drupal commerce 1.14
For an unknown reason groups of empty orders are being created with a status of Pending. Each group belongs to the same user. Seems to happen randomly.

Is there a way to track down what triggers this strange action. 
I can not find anything in the logs that helps.

Comment: Dumb question, are they clicking submit/order multiple times before the page reloads?

Comment: The orders are created when:
1) user logins in
2) same user completes the checkout process

The empty orders are created for 2 events, after login and after checkout. 
In the view: admin/commerce/orders the orders are all status=Pending and user=anonymous. However if I view any of these order's History the user is not anonymous but is the user that just checked out (or logged in). This does not happen for every user. 

I do not know what is triggering this action but would like to find out why and stop it.